# NSArrayM setObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Having a little issue with a bit of code, returning the error listed above after running its respective action:

```
- (IBAction)uploadData:(id)sender {

NSMutableArray *uploadArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[uploadArray addObject:@"hire.csv"];
[uploadArray addObject:@"equipment.csv"];
[uploadArray addObject:@"signature.png"];

NSString * docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

NSString * proof1 = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"proof1.png"];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: proof1])
{
    [uploadArray addObject:@"proof1.png"];
}

NSString * proof2 = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"proof2.png"];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: proof2])
{
    [uploadArray addObject:@"proof2.png"];
}

NSString * proof3 = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"proof3.png"];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: proof3])
{
    [uploadArray addObject:@"proof3.png"];
}

int arrayCount = [uploadArray count];
int i = 0;

NSString *arrayString;

for (i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
{
    uploadArray[i] = arrayString;

    if(arrayString != nil)
    {
    NSString * uploadString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:arrayString];
    [self upload:uploadString ftpUrl:@"ftp.xxxxxxxx.com/xx/xx" ftpUsr:@"xxx" ftpPass:@"xxx"];
    }

    NSLog(uploadArray[i]);

}

}
```

Now, if I disable everything in the for loop except for the `NSLog()` I get no error, and it returns the correct list of objects in the array.

This to me suggests that none of the objects should return nil, surely?

Could anyone help me spot what I'm doing wrong? (probably quite a lot as im pretty new to this stuff)

Comment: arrayString = uploadArray[i]; instead of uploadArray[i] = arrayString;

Comment: OK, apparently removing the string "arrayString" and using uploadArray[i] directly solved the issue. can anyone please explain why this is?

Comment: check the comment above. you do not set arrayString at all. it is always nil in your code.

Comment: Thanks got it now =), was writing mine as you were writing yours I think, as I didn't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error clearly stats, you are adding a nil object to an array and this is not allowed.

In the below code you have not assigned anything to `arrayString` making it nil. Then you try to add it to your array.

```
NSString *arrayString;

for (i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
{
    uploadArray[i] = arrayString;
```

From the looks of your code you are trying to add every element form your array to your string. You are doing this the wrong way around. You need a `NSMutableString` and do something like:

```
[arrayString appendString: uploadArray[i]];
```

Comment: Exactly (I was writing almost the same answer). Don't forget `uploadArray[i] = arrayString;` is compiled to `[uploadArray setObject:arrayString atIndex:i];`

Comment: Thanks for your input. That's not what the code is meant to achieve, rather the string was mean to be initialised outside of the for loop, and replaced by consecutive parts of the array until the array completes (I just typed the  line in the wrong order). The reason I've done it the way way i did was because each part of the array is later used to send an FTP upload request and I was having trouble getting multiple uploads to complete successfully on background threads. I thought (wrongly) that running a loop such as the above might have solved the issue